# How to check if a proxy server is configured?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, proxy

I have some code that runs fine when I have a web proxy defined in Internet Explorer. However if there is none defined it doesn't work. I want to check if the a proxy is defined. How would I change the below code to do that?

```
public DataTable GetCurrentFxPrices(string url)
{
    WebProxy wp = new WebProxy(WebProxy.GetDefaultProxy().Address.AbsoluteUri, true);
    wp.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

    WebClient wc = new WebClient();
    wc.Proxy = wp;

    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(wc.DownloadData(url));
    DataSet ds = new DataSet("fxPrices");
    ds.ReadXml(ms);

    DataTable dt = ds.Tables["Rate"];
    int i = dt.Rows.Count;
    return dt;
}
```

For example how would I download the data without using a proxy?

**UPDATE**

I have changed the code to the following

```
public DataTable GetCurrentFxPrices(string url)
{
    WebClient wc = new WebClient();

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(WebProxy.GetDefaultProxy().Address.AbsoluteUri))
    {
        WebProxy wp = new WebProxy(WebProxy.GetDefaultProxy().Address.AbsoluteUri, true);
        wp.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        wc.Proxy = wp;
    }            

    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(wc.DownloadData(url));
    DataSet ds = new DataSet("fxPrices");
    ds.ReadXml(ms);
    DataTable dt = ds.Tables["Rate"];

    int i = dt.Rows.Count;
    return dt;
}
```

I get the following error `System.NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code` on the if statement line.

**UPDATE 2**

I've also tried changing this line:

`if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(WebProxy.GetDefaultProxy().Address.AbsoluteUri))`

to

`if (WebProxy.GetDefaultProxy().Address.AbsoluteUri != null)`

but I get this error:

`System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Any ideas?

Comment: Without a proxy: Would omitting `wc.Proxy = wp;` do the trick? ("if there's no proxy, don't set it")

Comment: Did you know that WebProxy.GetDefaultProxy() is considerd obsolete? You should use WebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy() or WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy instead.

Comment: I've updated my question to use `GetSystemWebProxy`. Still having troubles, could you take a look?

Comment: I've tried testing the object for null, but still get an error. Any further ideas, people?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Remember, there is not one single "proxy address" or proxy Uri as you might think. Instead the proxy Uri may depend on each Uri to be retrieved, as can be seen in Internet Explorer's Proxy Settings dialog.

[image: Internet Explorer - Proxy Settings dialog]

The IWebProxy interface helps you to get the right proxy Uri, and tells you if this proxy will be used or bypassed for a specific Uri to be retrieved.

```
using System.Net;

Uri exampleUri = new Uri("http://www.example.org/")

IWebProxy defaultProxy = WebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy();

bool isBypassed = defaultProxy.IsBypassed(exampleUri);
// ... false

Uri proxyUri = defaultProxy.GetProxy(exampleUri);
// ... http://someproxy.mycorp.example:8080
```

In your method you would have to pass an IWebProxy interface, not a proxy address. The default proxy interface (like from [GetSystemWebProxy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.getsystemwebproxy.aspx)) is always set as a default.

If you want to set your own special proxy in case there is no proxy used for your Uri, you could do the following ...

```
public DataTable GetCurrentFxPrices(string url)
{
    Uri uri = new Uri(url);

    WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
    IWebProxy defaultProxy = WebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy();

    IWebProxy myProxy = new WebProxy(new Uri("http://myproxy:8080"))
    // if no bypass-list is specified, all Uris are to be retrieved via proxy

    if (defaultProxy.IsBypassed(uri))
    {
        myProxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        webClient.Proxy = myProxy;
    }            

    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(webClient.DownloadData(url));
    DataSet ds = new DataSet("fxPrices");
    ds.ReadXml(ms);
    DataTable dt = ds.Tables["Rate"];

    int i = dt.Rows.Count;
    return dt;
}
```

Comment: Note: One should not call both `IWebProxy.IsBypassed()` and `IWebProxy.GetProxy()` and expect the result to be consistent, since settings can change between the calls. (Especially if it comes from `WebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy()`.) [Comment split because of long URLs...]

Comment: If a call to `GetProxy()` is required, only way to safely determine if the proxy should be bypassed appears to be by [comparing the resulting `Uri` to see if it's the same as the original Uri](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system/net/System/Net/webproxy.cs,598).  (e.g. `isBypassed = (webProxy.GetProxy(uri) == uri`))  This however [isn't documented at all](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.iwebproxy.getproxy(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @antak You're right. Although the described problem seems a bit academic to me since proxy settings usually do not change all the time - especially not each msec. ;) So for most common cases one should be okay.

Answer (score 0):

Just call

```
if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(WebProxy.GetDefaultProxy().Address.AbsoluteUri))
{ 
    //do something you want if proxy is set
}
else
{
    //something else(proxy not set)
}
```

Comment: Yeah I thought of doing that but I'm not sure how I would configure the WebClient with no proxy. Any ideas there?

Answer (score 0):

Can you use the debugger and put a breakpoint on the if statement?

If I'm correct the `WebProxy.GetDefaultProxy()` call will return null and hence the `NullReferenceException`.

What happens if you change the code to:

```
if ((WebProxy.GetDefaultProxy() != null) && (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(WebProxy.GetDefaultProxy().Address.AbsoluteUri)))
```

I think it should solve your problem.

Comment: I'm trying now not to use `WebProxy.GetDefaultProxy()` as it's been marked as obsolete since V1. I want to use something like `IWebProxy iwp = WebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy()`. Any ideas on how to test for the existence of a proxy using that?

Comment: Just try to call it with no proxy configured. I expect iwp to be null, or an exception will get thrown.

Comment: My assumption was not correct, iwp is neither null nor will an exception be thrown.

It is however possible to check iwp.IsBypassed(Uri uri) for your target uri I think?